# How to remove underlying line when editing specific word in edit Text View

Tags: android, android-edittext, autosuggest, underline

this is what I tried and nothing works looked everywhere but found nothing

```
str.setTypeface(notoKyfiBold);
str.setText("دوس هنا للكتابه");
str.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
str.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
str.setFocusable(false);
str.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
str.setCursorVisible(false);
str.setClickable(false);
str.setMaxLines(15);
str.setEnabled(false);
str.setActivated(false);
str.setSingleLine(false);
str.setMaxTextSize(50);
str.setKeyListener(null);
str.setMinTextSize(0);
str.setHintTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
str.setBackground(null);
str.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
str.setSizeToFit(true);
str.setPadding(10,0,10,0);
str.endBatchEdit();
str.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
str.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(4);
str.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
str.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

the line is the one directly below the text, not that bottom border:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically, then you can use the following code.

```
//assume an EditText object with name myEditText
myEditText.setInputType(myEditText.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

> InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS does not seem to work as expected on all keyboards whereas InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD has the drawback that it also disables toggling the language in the keyboard and the swipe gesture to add the text.

Comment: thank you! i have been looking for this for 5hours and its actually simple and makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Just add following attribute in your edittext block in xml file:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: thank you ! this answer is also correct but i wanted in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of suggestions. You can turn them off using

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: thank you ! this answer is also correct but i wanted in code.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in EditText block

```
android:background="@null"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```